# Where does `go get` store what it downloads?

Tags: go

I have been informed to use `go get <github-URL>` to download a `go` program.

The command exists with no output and exit code `0`.

On my system both `$GOPATH` and `$GOROOT` are unset.

Where did `go` store my downloaded program?

Comment: have you checked your environment variables using `go env`.

Comment: @JimB Which the question says is unset.

Answer (score 9):

It stores in `GOPATH`. If you don't set it explicitly, it has default values (depending on your system).

https://go.dev/doc/code#ImportingRemote

> Module dependencies are automatically downloaded to the pkg/mod subdirectory of the directory indicated by the GOPATH environment variable

Comment: For me, it somehow mixes: When I clone [this repo](https://github.com/bogdanfinn/tls-client), then set `GOPATH=/tmp/go`, then do `go get`, it downloads _some_ stuff to `/tmp/go/`, and _some_ stuff to `${HOME}/.go/`. Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

[This go language issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17262) says that if the `GOPATH` environment variable is unset, then by default:

- `$HOME/go` is used on *NIX
- `%USERPROFILE%\go` is used on Windows